# Autopilot, Python Quickstart, ngrok 404 message

Tags: twilio

I am working my way through the Autopilot, Python Quickstart and keep hitting a barrier when trying to simulate the sms element. I was getting a 502 error, which I seem to have fixed, but I cannot get to the route of this error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpBjK.jpg)

Comment: Can you share the code to the Python Tutorial and your Flask route configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Ngrok screenshot you attached, you are forwarding to port 4040 (the Ngrok Debug port which has its own webserver with its own routes) rather then port 5000 (your Python Flask application) as used in the [Twilio Autopilot Python Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/quickstart/python-quickstart) Tutorial.